# Get elements in ion-footer-bar to line up directly below each other

Tags: css, ionic-framework

How do you get elements in [ion-footer-bar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionFooterBar/) to line up directly below each other rather than stack up next to each other?

**For example, this:**

[image]

**Is produced by the code below:**

```
<ion-footer-bar>
    <div>
        sdsd
    </div>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-positive">First</a>
        <a class="button button-positive">Second</a>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

In the example above, I'd like each element to be placed directly under each other, as opposed to next to each other.

Comment: Do you want *button-bar below ion-footer* or the buttons within *button within button-bar to be vertically aligned*? Its not clear from your last line

Comment: I want each element directly beneath each other within the ion-footer

Comment: why don't  you use *<br>* between the links(a tags) and after *div* containing **sdsd**.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to create another footer as you can see in this tuto : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_footer.htm

In your exemple, the solution would be :

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-subfooter>
    <div>
        sdsd
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-subfooter>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-positive">First</a>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
<ion-footer-bar>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <a class="button button-positive">Second</a>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```